# Custom build backend for Python

Tags: python, setuptools, python-packaging, pyproject.toml, pep517

I would like to write my own Python build backend that can used in `pyproject.toml` like

```
[build-system]
requires = ["setuptools>=42", "wheel", "mybackend"]
build-backend = "mybackend.build_meta"
```

and that does the *same* thing as setuptools, except that it preprends the line

```py
# nice code!
```

to each `.py` file. What entry points would `mybackend` have to provide, and is it possible to somehow "inherit" from setuptools?

Comment: You should make a fork of _setuptools_. I do not know what else to answer, building a back-end from scratch is not an easy task. -- Maybe you do not need a custom build back-end for this, maybe you can just override one of _setuptools_ command in order to add the line of text to each Python file, as long as these edited files end-up in the _sdist_ (and then _wheel_), that should be enough. I do not recall which setuptools command you would need to call for this. Maybe this helps: https://sinoroc.gitlab.io/kb/python/setuptools.html

Comment: Or you can investigate [in-tree build](https://peps.python.org/pep-0517/#in-tree-build-backends) to monkey-patch setuptools or something like that. Maybe that works.

Answer (score 0):

One way to extend `setuptools` is to use wrap those in your own `build_wheel`/`build_sdist` like

```py
from setuptools.build_meta import build_sdist as setuptools_build_sdist
from setuptools.build_meta import build_wheel as setuptools_build_wheel


def build_wheel(wheel_directory, config_settings=None, metadata_directory=None):
    return setuptools_build_wheel(
        wheel_directory,
        config_settings=config_settings,
        metadata_directory=metadata_directory,
    )


def build_sdist(sdist_directory, config_settings=None):
    return setuptools_build_sdist(sdist_directory, config_settings)
```

Instead of immediately returning the output of the setuptools functions (e.g., the tar-file), one can work on those files.